# Ajax FileUpload & JQuery formData in ASP.NET MVC not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, form-data

I am struggling with this for a day now. I know this thread has been accessed often before but I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. I ll post the code here and I hope you could see if it is something amiss.

```
var chunk = new File([fileChunks[currentPart - 1]], fileName);

    if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', chunk, fileName);
        formData.append("fileName", fileName);
        }

    //var blobFile = blobToFile(fileChunks[currentPart - 1], fileName, testFile.type)


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: my.static.uploadLargeFileUrl,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('uploading file part ' + currentPart + "out of " + totalPart)
            if (response.status == true) {
                if (currentPart == totalPart) { console.log('whole file uploaded'); }
                else { uploadFileChunk(fileChunks, fileName, currentPart + 1, totalPart); }
            }
            else {
                console.log('failed to upload part' + currentPart);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
        //retry message to upload rest of the file
            console.log("error to upload file part no: " + currentPart);
            uploadFileChunk(fileChunks, fileName, currentPart, totalPart);
    }

    });
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. `Is not working` is no error message. Pelase post full error message and stacktrace.

Comment: Hello and thanks. It is not an error, it sends the message to server side, but can t do the binding properly. I mean it does not recognize the sent file as a file like it is expected. Server side: Request.Files.Count  = 0

Comment: remove datatype : json and then try

Comment: Already tried that. It s not critical for me, but still it s kinda frustrating.